# How to bind timestamp values in NodeJS for to insert into Oracle DB?

Tags: javascript, typescript, oracle

I have a NodeJS app and I am using oracledb npm package to send data to oracle db. I have  table that looks like this:

```
EVENT_ID          NUMBER(38,0)
EVENT_TIMESTAMP   TIMESTAMP(6)
EVENT_TYPE        NUMBER(38,0)
```

I built the query and set the binds but I am not able to get the timestamp binding working. This is how the query looks:

```
sql = `INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(
        EVENT_ID,
        EVENT_TIMESTAMP,
        EVENT_TYPE
        )
        VALUES(
        ${event.id}, 
        '${new Date(event.isoDate).slice(0, 19).replace("T", " ")}', //Convert iso date to MS SQL format
        ${event.type}
        )`;
```

And here are the bindings:

```
export const EventsOracleBinds = {
  EVENT_ID: { type: oracledb.DB_TYPE_NUMBER, maxSize: 38 },
  EVENT_TIMESTAMP: { type: oracledb.DB_TYPE_TIMESTAMP },
  EVENT_TYPE: { type: oracledb.DB_TYPE_NUMBER, maxSize: 38 },
};
```

If I console.log(sql) and copy-paste it in MSSQL, it is able to insert the row.

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong in my Node application?

Comment: Your SQL statement doesn't appear to be using bind names so are you actually binding or using string concatenation to put the data in the statement?  The latter is a security and scalability problem.  Review how to bind in the two node-oracledb examples [date_timestamp1.js](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/main/examples/date_timestamp1.js) and [date_timestamp2](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/main/examples/date_timestamp2.js).